# Google Ads API ConversionTrackerService - return only single conversion

Tags: python, reporting, google-ads-api, conversion-tracking

I am trying to fetch the conversions data from the **Google Ads API** using the ConversionTrackerService. I have 5 conversions in my Google Ads account (refer to the screenshot) but I am getting only 1 in the response.

Also in the selector object, I have added just 2 fields, Category, and Name, but in the response, I am getting all the fields.

Can someone please guide me on what I am doing wrong?

```
adwords_client = adwords.AdWordsClient({...})

adwords_client.SetClientCustomerId('xxx-xxx-xxxx')

def conversion_tracker_service():
    campaign_service = adwords_client.GetService('ConversionTrackerService', version='v201809')

    selector = {
        'fields': ['Category', 'Name'],
        'paging': {
            'startIndex': str(0),
            'numberResults': str(10)
        }
    }

    page = campaign_service.get(selector)

    print(page)

conversion_tracker_service()
```

Response:

```
{
    'totalNumEntries': 1,
    'Page.Type': 'ConversionTrackerPage',
    'entries': [
        {
            'id': 285131182,
            'originalConversionTypeId': None,
            'name': 'Text Messaging & SMS for Business -- HighLevel (Android) installs',
            'status': 'ENABLED',
            'category': 'DOWNLOAD',
            'googleEventSnippet': None,
            'googleGlobalSiteTag': None,
            'dataDrivenModelStatus': None,
            'conversionTypeOwnerCustomerId': None,
            'viewthroughLookbackWindow': 1,
            'ctcLookbackWindow': 30,
            'countingType': 'ONE_PER_CLICK',
            'defaultRevenueValue': 1.0,
            'defaultRevenueCurrencyCode': 'USD',
            'alwaysUseDefaultRevenueValue': True,
            'excludeFromBidding': False,
            'attributionModelType': 'LAST_CLICK',
            'mostRecentConversionDate': None,
            'lastReceivedRequestTime': None,
            'ConversionTracker.Type': 'AppConversion',
            'appId': 'com.gohighlevel',
            'appPlatform': 'ANDROID_MARKET',
            'snippet': None,
            'appConversionType': 'DOWNLOAD',
            'appPostbackUrl': None
        }
    ]
}
```

[image: Google Ads Platform Conversions Page Screenshot]

Comment: Any updates on this?

Answer (score 2):

I can reproduce `ConversionTrackerService` always returning [all default fields](https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/selectorfields#get_24) of the `ConversionTracker` object. Fields that depend on the specific type of the conversion such as `WebsitePhoneCallDuration` have to be explicitly included in the selector, though. Seems to be undocumented behavior.

As for the missing conversions — anything imported from Google Analytics is currently not being returned by the `ConversionTrackerService` — [confirmed on the Adwords API Forum](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/adwords-api/epmSNso-OJk/eSvGZH-bFQAJ).

I'm somewhat certain that "Chats from ads" aren't supported (yet) over the API.

That explains 3 out of the missing 4 conversions. The "Calls from ads" conversion *should* be returned as an Conversion object of type `AdCallMetricsConversion`, which works for those accounts that I have tested, so I am not sure what the problem with your code is.